# How to install touchscreen on Acer Spin SP314-53N?

Tags: keyboard, acer, touchscreen, multi-touch

I'm requesting instructions to install the ability to use the touchscreen and screen keyboard for the Acer Spin SP314-53N.

After installing Ubuntu, I could no longer use the touchscreen.

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS is the current version installed.

Is it important which version of Ubuntu is installed to the specific model of computer?

What is needed to install the touchscreen keyboard?